# Simple PHP function not working strange enough

Tags: php, function

I have a very simple PHP function which checks the DB if the post is saved in the user's bookmarks or not. If it is saved as a bookmark in the table 'bookmarks', it should return a link to the bookmarks, if not, it should return a simple button.

This is the code that calls the function:

```
echo bookmark($id,'stories');
```

This is the PHP function:

```
function bookmark($id,$column) {

  global $db_conx;

  if($column = 'stories') { $col = 'storid'; }
  elseif($column = 'discussions') { $col = 'discid'; }
  elseif($column = 'articles') { $col = 'articleid'; }
  elseif($column = 'videos') { $col = 'videoid'; }
  else $col = 'resid';

  $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE '$col'='$id' AND username='$log_username' LIMIT 1");
  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($num_rows > 0) {
  return "<a class='rllink' title='Saved in your bookmarks' href='https://hangar.flights/bookmarks'><i class='fa fa-bookmark'></i></a>";
  }
  else return "<a class='rllink' href="xxxx" title='Save this in your bookmarks'><i class='fa fa-bookmark-o'></i></a>";
};
```

For some weird reason, this doesn't seem to be working, although my other similar functions do work. Everywhere I call this function (with the correct parameters) it returns the else statement, even if the specific id is saved in the bookmarks and should return the first statement with a link to the bookmarks.

Anyone who sees what's wrong with it? I have tried adapting and changing it but nothing works.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to code injection (via $id). Use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using assignment-in-if:

```
if($column = 'stories')
```

When executed, this is what happens:

1. the value of $column becomes the string 'stories'
2. the if statement checks whether the new value of $column is truthy

This is almost certainly *not* what you want, and you'll probably want to do comparing-if statements that don't change the value(s) of the things you check:

```
if($column == 'stories')
```

This will check whether $column is currently equal to the string 'stories' without changing the value.

Comment: Oh of course, what a stupid mistake of me! Thanks a lot for the quick reply, I feel kind of embarrassed lol..